# Why my ibus input can't type 'que' or 'qve' in Chinese?

Tags: ibus

I'm using Ubuntu14.04 combining with wmii.

But I can't type 'que' or 'qve' to get Chinese character '缺'.

What to do ?

Comment: I have no trouble typing it with either que or qve. I doubt wmii has anything to do with it. Do you know which pinyin library you are using?

Comment: @chaskes, how to check that? When I type qvo, it returns me '去v哦'

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to change this behavior is to use the Ibus Intelligent Pinyin engine rather than the default pinyin engine.

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin
```

Then add the `Chinese - Intelligent Pinyin` input method and remove the standard `Chinese - Pinyin` option from your input methods. (Just remove the input method from your list. Don't uninstall any packages.)

You may need to logout after installing `ibus-libpinyin` before the intelligent pinyin option shows up.